# How to account for servlet path mapping when rendering paths for swagger service description

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, swagger, swagger-ui

I have problem with configuring swagger. When I specify link for servlet in web.xml like

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

swagger shows url-s without .../rest/... so I can't use swagger-ui for testing, when I specify url-pattern /* swagger-ui don't work. Here is configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
public class DocumentationController extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;
    @Autowired
    public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig) {
        this.springSwaggerConfig = springSwaggerConfig;
    }
    @Bean
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation() {
        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig).apiInfo(
                apiInfo())
                .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
                .includePatterns("/.*");
    }
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("1-st Project's REST API",
                "Write a description of REST API.",
                "link",
                "mail",
                "API License",
                "link");
        return apiInfo;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you should show us your swagger-ui JS config.

Comment: @RC. I am newbie in js what file it can be?

Comment: see https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#swaggerui

Comment: This is unrelated to the swagger-ui configuration. This relates to the `basePath` configuration in swagger-springmvc/springfox (whichever @user3378876 is using).

Comment: @RC. ok it`s works when i specify not empty value in url-pattern parameter but I can't test because swagger writes url without with value. For example: I specify url-pattern parameter /rest/* and swagger shows only  /login instead of /rest/login so swagger-ui won't works fine

Comment: @Ron I believe you are right but can't figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: Which do you use? swagger-springmvc or springfox?

Comment: @Ron swagger-springmvc

Comment: Then I'd recommend upgrading to springfox, which is the renamed (newer and better) version of swagger-springmvc. It provides you with Swagger 2.0 definitions which is great, and they provide *a lot* documentation on how to set up your environment and such.

Comment: @Ron I have some difficult problem with migration spring fox have no jars for SpringSwaggerConfig and SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin classes. And I don't found how to change them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're using pre 2.0.0 version of springfox.

The solution is a little tricky and its not really tested, so no guarantees on this working, but its worth a shot.

```java
//NOTE: The following code is only an outline to highlight relevant code snippets
@Bean 
public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin plugin() {
    new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(...)
        //more config
        .pathProvider(yourPathProvider());
}

private SwaggerPathProvider yourPathProvider() {
    SwaggerPathProvider pathProvider = new RelativeSwaggerPathProvider(...);
    pathProvider.setApiResourcePrefix("/rest"); //<-- NOTE: this is what you need
    return pathProvider;
}
```

Now its much easier if you move to 2.x. There is even a [document](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/docs/transitioning-to-v2.md) that describes how to migrate to 2.x from 1.x.

```java
@Bean 
public Docket plugin() {
    new Docket()
        //more config
        .pathMapping("/rest");

}
```

Also keep in mind there are no planned updates for 1.x. So its a good idea to move to 2.0.0 of the library.